# Access Tomcat with a public IP address

Tags: tomcat

I installed tomcat9 on a windows server with a x.x.x.x ip adress. When I start tomcat the only way to access it is wether localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8080. My need is to be able to access it also from the x.x.x.x ip address of the server.

I added this property adress = "0.0.0.0" to the Connector of the server.xml yet no changes are noticed.

Have you any ideas about how to achieve this?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 instead of x.x.x.x

Comment: @maio290 I did it but it doesn't change anything. I still can't access tomcat from an other public ip address

Comment: Are you sure that your server has a public facing network interface with an public ip assigned to it? If yes, we should be able to reach it as well.

If tomcat binds to all interfaces, i guess your problem is not tomcat but your general setup. More Details would be great.

Comment: @LeonG the issue was that the port 8080 was closed. I couldn't listen from it with a public address